# componentDidUpdate is firing constantly or never firing

Tags: reactjs, redux

So this is my code for component did update and this.props.getQuestions() is constantly firing. questions property is an array of questions which takes the values of the global state.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){

        if(prevProps.questions !== this.props.questions){    
            this.props.getQuestions();
        }

    }
```

Connecting state to props

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  questions: state.question.questions
});
```

When I try to compare the length of array between prevState and the current state, the method is never fired.

```
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps){

        if(prevProps.questions.length !== this.props.questions.length){    
            this.props.getQuestions();
        }

    }
```

How to make it work, so this method is fired only when the array is updated?

Answer (score 1):

Simple array compare doesn't work. It will always match your condition ie. always not equal. And thus, componentDidUpdate fires constantly. Rather, you should check it like:

```
if(JSON.stringify(prevProps.questions) !== JSON.stringify(this.props.questions)){    
   this.props.getQuestions();
}
```

Regarding the checking with `length` property, it should work fine. But you stated that it isn't working. It seems you get same array when you use getQuestions. Check that function properly that it gets updated questions.

Comment: Good and quick workaround, but can we guarantee that props order won't change? Which would stringify differently and the comparison would fail

Comment: Yeah, the order will not change.

Comment: Correct answer. Should be "the chosen one".

Answer (score 0):

Your condition for fire was not right which you can see with your comparison of length of the array. You are checking for the equality of array's reference which is anyways incorrect(not sure how redux handles the prop update though).

You drill down to specificity of the questions in comparison and can compare questions' length, questions' questionId etc.. Loop through them and identify as desired.

You can even use library like lodash https://lodash.com/docs to compare array's and specific property.

Answer (score 0):

If `questions` is the only property in mapStateToProps() you could just ensure you create a new array wherever you update it

`newState.question.questions = [...updatedArray];`

and remove the if statement from your componentDidUpdate entirely.

Make sure you do not update the `questions` array when calling `getQuestions()`, doing that can cause infinite loops where your didUpdate function causes an update (triggers didUpdate, ad infinitum)